# 400 Bad Request while uploading file in Altair using graphql and apollo

Tags: node.js, file-upload, graphql, apollo, graphql-js

[image]

400 Bad Request while uploading file in Altair using graphql and apollo
here is my code when I send a request to the server only in uploading file I get this kind of error: is there any way I could upload a file without getting this error

```
const {  gql } = require('apollo-server-express');

  
export default gql`
   scalar Upload
   type User{
    id: Int! 
    firstName: String!
    lastName:  String!
    userName:  String! 
    email:     String! 
    createdAt: String!
    updatedAt: String!
    bio:       String
    avatar:    String

   }
   type loginResult{
    ok:    Boolean!
    token: String
    Error: String

   }
   type editProfileResult{
    ok: Boolean!
    Error: String
   }
   type Mutation{
    creatUser(
        firstName: String!
        lastName:  String!
        userName:  String! 
        email:     String! 
        password:  String!
    
    ):User
    logIn(userName: String!, password: String!):loginResult!
    editProfile(firstName: String
        lastName:  String
        userName:  String
        email:     String 
        password:  String
        bio:        String
        avatar:    Upload ):editProfileResult!
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and figured that I should use the `graphqlUploadExpress` from `graphql-upload` in my node.js server.

```
import { graphqlUploadExpress } from 'graphql-upload/graphqlUploadExpress.mjs';

app.use(graphqlUploadExpress());
```

Answer (score 1):

Using below worked for me!

```
import { graphqlUploadExpress } from 'graphql-upload/graphqlUploadExpress.mjs';

app.use(graphqlUploadExpress());
```

Comment: Hi, I am using the same code, but When uploading the Image using expo web and expo image throws an error of not JSON object.  If doc on how to use expo web and Appolo upload. I will grateful. thanks